# Python Pandas: Self-join for running cumulative total, with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Python Pandas and hence am unable to find the syntactic equivalent of many mundane SQL operations. Given the toy scenario:

```
id    rank   ts          alive
1     1      2015-11-01  1
1     2      2015-11-03  1
1     3      2015-11-07  1
2     1      2015-11-03  1
2     2      2015-11-08  1
```

How would I achieve the following:

```
id    rank   ts          alive   cumulative_age_in_days   mean_id_age_on_this_date
1     1      2015-11-01  1       0                        0
1     2      2015-11-03  1       2                        1
1     3      2015-11-07  1       6                        5
2     1      2015-11-03  1       0                        1
2     2      2015-11-08  1       5                        6
```

where `cumulative_day_age` is the current row's date minus the earliest date for an ID. For example, on `2015-11-03`, `id=1` is 2 days old, since it was first observed at `2015-11-01`. On `2015-11-07`, it is 6 days old ( `2015-11-07` - `2015-11-01`).

and where `mean_id_age_on_this_date` is the mean age of the all `id` on this row's date, if the `id` has `alive = 1`. So for `2015-11-03`, `id=1` is 2 days old, but `id=2` is 0 days old, so `mean_id_age_on_this_date` is (0+2)/2 = 1.

These two columns are easy to do in SQL but I lack familiarity with Python Pandas at the same degree so this is an unbelievably challenging task. Any hints, code or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First subtract first minimal day per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `min` and then output timedeltas convert to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html), then convert values not matched `df['alive'].eq(1)` to misisng values in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and use `GroupBy.transform` with `mean`:

```
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'])

df['cumulative_age_in_days'] = df['ts'].sub(df.groupby('id')['ts'].transform('min')).dt.days

df['mean_id_age_on_this_date'] = (df['cumulative_age_in_days'].where(df['alive'].eq(1))
                                                              .groupby(df['ts'])
                                                              .transform('mean'))
print (df)
   id  rank         ts  alive  cumulative_age_in_days  \
0   1     1 2015-11-01      1                       0   
1   1     2 2015-11-03      1                       2   
2   1     3 2015-11-07      1                       6   
3   2     1 2015-11-03      1                       0   
4   2     2 2015-11-08      1                       5   

   mean_id_age_on_this_date  
0                         0  
1                         1  
2                         6  
3                         1  
4                         5
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`Groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
In [1538]: df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts']) # Convert `ts` to `datetime`

In [1547]: df['cumulative_age_in_days'] = df.ts.dt.day - df.groupby('id')['ts'].transform('min').dt.day

In [1556]: df['mean_id_age_on_this_date'] = df[df.alive.eq(1)].groupby('ts')['cumulative_age_in_days'].transform('mean')

In [1557]: df
Out[1557]: 
   id  rank         ts  alive  cumulative_age_in_days  mean_id_age_on_this_date
0   1     1 2015-11-01      1                       0                         0
1   1     2 2015-11-03      1                       2                         1
2   1     3 2015-11-07      1                       6                         6
3   2     1 2015-11-03      1                       0                         1
4   2     2 2015-11-08      1                       5                         5
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def converDate(string):
  return datetime.strptime(string, "%Y-%m-%d")

def getEarly(data):
  min_date = sorted(data["ts"].map(converDate))[0]
  data["cumulative_age_in_days"] = data["ts"].map(lambda el : (converDate(el) - min_date).days)
  return data

def getMean(data): 
  data["mean_id_age_on_this_date"] = int(sum(data["cumulative_age_in_days"]) / len(data))
  return data

data1 = data.groupby("id").apply(getEarly)
data2 = data1.groupby("ts").apply(getMean)
data2
```